# VBA Code throwing Compile Error: Expected Array

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I have a CSV file that contains lots of tables inside of one worksheet. I was writing parts of the code in one procedure to check if it was doing what I expected for each table. The final result I pasted in one single procedure and now I'm getting a Compile Error right in the beginning of the code, in "Sub IP_VBA()", and I have no idea how to solve it, can someone help me?
If I run it part by part, it does what I want, but not when I put all the code together.

```vb
Sub IP_VBA()
    ' Format IP table
    
    Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long, LR3 As Long, LR4 As Long, LR5 As Long
    Dim FR1 As Long, FR2 As Long, FR3 As Long, FR4 As Long
    Dim Rows As Long, i As Long
    Dim Data As Range
    
    'Delete tables 1, 2 and 3
    Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Delete
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Delete
    Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.Delete
    
    'Get necessary data from table 4
    LR1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Range("B1:B" & LR1 & "," & "D1:E" & LR1 & "," _
        & "G1:O" & LR1).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    'Delete table 5
    Rows(LR1 + 2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    'Get necessary data from table 6
    FR1 = Range("A" & LR1).Offset(2, 0).Row
    Rows(FR1).EntireRow.Delete
    LR2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & FR1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + LR1 + 1
    Range("A" & FR1 & ":B" & LR2 & "," & "E" & FR1 & ":J" & LR2 & "," & _
        "L" & FR1 & ":T" & LR2).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    'Get necessary data from tables 7 and 8
    FR2 = Range("A" & LR2).Offset(2, 0).Row
    Rows(FR2).EntireRow.Delete
    LR3 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & FR2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + LR2 + 1
    FR3 = Range("A" & LR3).Offset(2, 0).Row
    Rows(FR3).EntireRow.Delete
    LR3 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & FR3).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + LR3 + 1
    Range("A" & FR2 & ":D" & LR3 & "," & "G" & FR2 & ":L" & LR3 & "," & _
        "N" & FR2 & ":V" & LR3).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        
    'Delete table 9
    FR4 = Range("A" & LR3).Offset(2, 0).Row
    LR4 = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & FR4).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + LR3 + 1
    Range("A" & FR4 & ":W" & LR4).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    'Delete Empty Rows
    LR5 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Data = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C" & LR5)
    Rows = Data.Rows.Count
    For i = Rows To 1 Step (-1)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Data.Rows(i)) = 0 Then Data.Rows(i).Delete
    Next
    
    'Rename Columns
    Range("A1").Formula = "Part Number"
    Range("B1").Formula = "IP Qty"
    Range("C1").Formula = "IP Value"
    
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Please indicate the line of your code that prompts the compile error

Comment: Any code above the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

`Dim Rows As Long`

but then

`Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Delete`

I would not use `Rows` as a variable name, and also use a specific worksheet qualifier for any and all calls to Rows/Range/Cells/Columns

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Delete
'etc
```

Comment: Ohhh yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I named it as a dumb name just to check if that last part would work and totally forgot to change it. Thank you so much.